# Angular 2 can't loop array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, ionic-framework

So I have the following array structure:

> ['a name' => [Array, Array], 'another name' => [Array] ....]

Here is a dump.

[image]

> Setting the value

```
(this.reservationGroups[businessName] = this.reservationGroups[businessName] || []).push(reservation);
```

Now in my view, I'm trying to test this:

```
<ion-list inset class="reservation-list">
    <ion-item *ngFor="let slot of reservationGroups">
        <ion-icon name="clock"></ion-icon>
        test
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

But it doesn't do anything

Comment: Does it work with a different array like `[1,2,3]`?

Comment: yes it works, i tested

Comment: Your array seems to be an associative array. I guess that's not supported.